# I have a French Coconut pie recipe that calls for 1/2 cup butter. Could I replace it with condensed milk instead?

Tags: substitutions, butter

I have a coconut pie recipe that uses 1/2 cup butter and 3 eggs.  Could I replace some of the butter with condensed milk?  Any other substitutes besides margarine?

Comment: Are you sure it's 1 cup of butter, could it be 1 stick of butter? A quick Google search of recipes showed all using 1/2 cup (1 stick).

Comment: Sorry about that, yes you are right, Debbie.  It's 1/2 cup.  I would like to cut back on the butter without affecting taste or texture.

Comment: How is the butter used? Is it creamed, melted, or just whisked into the ingredients?

Comment: melted and then stirred into rest of ingredients.

Answer (score 3):

Butter is about 80% fat, maybe a bit lower if you're getting it direct from the farmer; condensed milk is about 10% fat, so you'd need to use a *lot* of condensed milk and you'd probably have too much excess water to compensate by reducing extra liquids.

The best substitute would be another fat which is solid at room temperature. There aren't many (at least, not if you restrict to vegetable fats), but one which does meet the criterion is coconut oil, and since you're making a coconut pie that seems like an excellent substitute.

Answer (score 1):

It will not come out the same. Butter and condensed milk are not really similar. Consenses or evaporated milk is what gives key lime pie filing its consistency. Coconut cream you want more of a pudding or custard like consistency.

Comment: This is not the same as coconut cream pie.  It's not a custard type filling. More like a pecan pie filling but thicker.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, butter is somehow far away from condensed milk so I don't think you can use condensed milk as a substitution of butter at all. your pie will turn out totally different. As opposed to butter, you can use oil instead such as vegetable oil or coconut oil, both will work well. hope it helps. cheers